# How to dynamically combine interfaces in Kotlin?

Tags: oop, kotlin, design-patterns, jvm

I am not sure how to word the question in a more correct fashion or how to come up with an example that is less contrived.

Let's say that I have an interface that describes some fields (`Data` in my example).

I then want to apply some transformations to it (sum and multiply the fields in my example). Ideally, this should be like a data pipeline configurable at runtime by the user of the application (via a config file, for example). I also define interfaces for properties that get added to my object by each of the transformations (`SummedData` and `MultipliedData`).

I also define some classes (`DataSummer` and `DataMultiplier`) that implement these interfaces as well as the original `Data` interface, so they can be "cascaded" and applied one after the other. In my example, these are very simple, but you can imagine them lazily calling into external APIs or doing some expensive processing.

Everything works, except each subsequent transformation removes the type information of the previous one (in my example, `data is SummedData` is always true and `data is MultipliedData` is always false despite them both being applied to the original object). What I want is both of the checks to be true no matter the order I apply the transformations.

I have an idea of how to do this in a more dynamic language like Python, but I wonder if something similar can be done with Kotlin.

Code example:

```kotlin
interface Data {
    val field1 : Int
    val field2 : Int
}

interface SummedData  {
    val fSum : Int
}

interface MultipliedData {
    val fProd : Int
}

data class DataSummer(private val iData : Data, private val iSum : SummedData) : Data by iData, SummedData by iSum{
    constructor(data : Data) : this(
        data,
        object:SummedData {override val fSum:Int = data.field1 + data.field2}
    )
}

data class DataMultiplier(private val iData : Data, private val iMul : MultipliedData) : Data by iData, MultipliedData by iMul{
    constructor(data : Data) : this(
        data,
        object:MultipliedData {override val fProd:Int = data.field1 * data.field2}
    )
}

fun main() {
    var data:Data = object : Data {
        override val field1 = 2
        override val field2 = 3}

    data = DataMultiplier(data)
    data = DataSummer(data)

    //Always false :(
    if (data is MultipliedData){
        println("Product of ${data.field1} and ${data.field2} is ${data.fProd}" )
    }
    if (data is SummedData){
        println("Sum of ${data.field1} and ${data.field2} is ${data.fSum}" )
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: You don't _actually_ want `data is MultipliedData` to be true, right? What you _actually_ want is to be able to access `fProd`. Is that right?

Comment: Well, I actually want to be able to access `fProd`, but I also want to check if it's there, since in my imagination, the decision whether to run `data = DataMultiplier(data)` or not is based on some form of user input

Comment: Are you trying to recreate the decorator pattern by any chance?

Comment: Kind of, but I want to be able to combine decorators arbitrarily and to keep the information on what decorators were applied to an object. (I've been looking at the Gang of Four all day today to no avail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> subsequent transformation removes the type information of the previous one

If you want to keep this information, you need to store it explicitly:

```kotlin
//abstract class is used here instead of interface to introduce its property as private
//pass thread-safe implementation of MutableList into constructor if you are about to add mixins in multiple threads
abstract class DataWithMixins(private val mixins: MutableList<Any> = ArrayList()) : Data {
    fun addMixin(mixin: Any): DataWithMixins {
        mixins.add(mixin)
        return this //to allow chaining calls
    }

    inline fun <reified T : Any> getMixin(): T? = getMixinOfType(T::class) as? T

    //mediator-function to access non-public API from public-API inline function
    fun getMixinOfType(type: KClass<*>): Any? = mixins.find { type.isInstance(it) }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val data = object : DataWithMixins() {
        override val field1 = 2
        override val field2 = 3
    }

    data.addMixin(DataSummer(data))
        .addMixin(DataMultiplier(data))

    //get mixin of interface type
    data.getMixin<SummedData>()?.run {
        println("Sum of ${data.field1} and ${data.field2} is $fSum")
    }
    data.getMixin<MultipliedData>()?.run {
        println("Product of ${data.field1} and ${data.field2} is $fProd")
    }

    //get mixin of class type, now we can access field1 & field2 directly
    data.getMixin<DataSummer>()?.run {
        println("Sum of $field1 and $field2 is $fSum")
    }
    data.getMixin<DataMultiplier>()?.run {
        println("Product of $field1 and $field2 is $fProd")
    }
}
```

To make API for mixin addition as nice as its getter, we will have to:

1. Use reflection
2. Implicitly (no comlile-time error, but runtime) restrict mixins, that could be added in this way based on a possibility of its unambigous instantiation from `data: Data` (or without any source). In the following implementation these mixins are:

   1. Singletons (aka object classes)
   2. Classes with constructor which has no more than one `Data` parameter (because we won't use its default value, but will pass our own) and either has no other parameters or all other parameters are optional (this includes no-arg constructors)

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> DataWithMixins.addMixin(): DataWithMixins {
    val objectInstance = T::class.objectInstance
    val mixin = when {
        objectInstance != null -> objectInstance
        else -> {
            //there is no more than one Data parameter
            //AND
            //there is no more than one mandatory parameter and it is Data
            var niceConstructor: KFunction<T>? = null
            var dataParameter: KParameter? = null
            constructorsLoop@
            for (constructor in T::class.constructors) {
                dataParameter = null
                var mandatoryParametersCounter = 0
                for (param in constructor.parameters) {
                    val isMandatory = !param.isOptional
                    val isData = param.type.classifier == Data::class
                    if (isData) {
                        dataParameter = if (dataParameter == null) param else continue@constructorsLoop
                        if (isMandatory && ++mandatoryParametersCounter > 1) continue@constructorsLoop
                    } else if (isMandatory) continue@constructorsLoop
                }
                if (mandatoryParametersCounter == 0 || dataParameter != null) {
                    niceConstructor = constructor
                    break@constructorsLoop
                }
            }
            if (niceConstructor == null) error("${T::class} can't be auto-instantiated as a mixin for Data")
            if (dataParameter == null) {
                niceConstructor.call()
            } else {
                niceConstructor.callBy(mapOf(dataParameter to this))
            }
        }
    }
    //can't access non-public API from public-API inline function directly, so will use this method as mediator
    return addMixin(mixin)
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
    data.addMixin<DataSummer>()
        .addMixin<DataMultiplier>()

//instead of

//  data.addMixin(DataSummer(data))
//      .addMixin(DataMultiplier(data))
```

Also I believe your `DataSummer` and `DataMultiplier`classes could be simplified:

```kotlin
data class DataSummer(private val iData: Data) : Data by iData, SummedData {
    override val fSum: Int = iData.field1 + iData.field2
}

data class DataMultiplier(private val iData: Data) : Data by iData, MultipliedData {
    override val fProd: Int = iData.field1 * iData.field2
}
```